# Unsatisfied reference in OSGi declarative service component

Tags: eclipse, osgi, apache-felix, equinox, declarative-services

I have a problem with an unsatisfied reference in an OSGi declarative service component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0"
    name="com.mycompany.foo.Service"
    immediate="true"
    activate="activate"
    deactivate="deactivate">
<implementation class="com.mycompany.foo.Service"/>
<!-- Other references -->
<reference
        interface="org.osgi.service.http.HttpService"
        name="HttpService"
        cardinality="1..1"
        policy="static"
        bind="setHttpService"
        unbind="unsetHttpService"/>
</scr:component>
```

I launch the OSGi application from Eclipse, and the console shows the service is in the `Unsatisfied` state:

```
osgi> ls
All Components:
ID    State            Component Name            Located in bundle
6    Unsatisfied        com.mycompany.foo.Service            com.mycompany.foo(bid=18)
```

The `comp` command reports the reason is an unsatisfied reference to `org.osgi.service.http`:

```
osgi> comp 6
Component[
    name = com.mycompany.foo.Service
    ...
    state = Unsatisfied
    references = {
        ...
        Reference[name = HttpService, interface = org.osgi.service.http.HttpService, policy = static, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = setHttpService, unbind = unsetHttpService]
    }
    located in bundle = com.mycompany.foo_1.2.3 [18]
]
Dynamic information :
   *The component is NOT satisfied
   The following references are not satisfied:
     Reference[name = HttpService, interface = org.osgi.service.http.HttpService, policy = static, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = setHttpService, unbind = unsetHttpService]
   Component configurations :
     Configuration properties:
       component.name = com.mycompany.foo.Service
       component.id = 6
     Instances:
```

But `org.osgi.service.http` is available as the `packages` command shows:

```
osgi> p org.osgi.service.http
org.osgi.service.http; version="1.2.1"<org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.2.100.v20100503 [54]>
  com.mycompany.foo_1.2.3 [18] imports
  org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry_1.1.1.R36x_v20101103 [46] imports
  org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.1.0.v20100503 [47] imports
  org.eclipse.equinox.http.servletbridge_1.0.200.v20100503 [48] imports
```

I tried removing the reference from the service document and the service component is instantiated and activated correctly, but without the essential `HttpService` piece.

Any help to troubleshoot further is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that your component requires an implementation of the HttpService. You do not have one available.

The "p" command only reports on static packages. You have the `org.osgi.service.http` API package available, but you need a bundle that actually implements the API and provides the service.

I recommend adding the `org.apache.felix.http.jetty` bundle, which contains an easy-to-use implementation of HttpService.

Comment: Thanks Neil, I will try that now. The implementation should be made available by `org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.HttpServiceImpl`.

Comment: That's the name of a class which is private inside a bundle. You shouldn't need to care about that -- you only care about which bundle provides the service.

Comment: Turns out there were missing bundles in my workspace. My project required cherry-picking a minimum set from a broader repository of bundles. The target platform required more bundles than those I originally picked. I guess the absence of runtime errors in such circumstances is by design?